# What is your data loading strategy for pins on the map on the iOS?

Tags: ios, dictionary, fetching-strategy

I have developed an iOS app with native map showing custom pins on the map? Data behind the pins is loaded on demand and based on the movement around the map. I am setting a radius based on the current position and if the map goes out of this region it will send for data update. 
At first new pins are loading smoothly but sometimes I have a feeling they are lagging especially for quick swipes.
So what strategies are you using in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Apps that I have worked on that have maps I normally use the bounding box rather than radius as it is a perfect match for the screen ie rectangular.

As for loading new pois when a user moves, I would wait until they have stopped scrolling the map.  If your users are doing quick swipes you could always detect that the map has moved and cancel any existing requests that were being executed until the user stops moving again.

Comment: I've read that rectangular geo search takes more time to calculate all bounding results so I am using and radius where the value is the length from center to edge.
Also I am cancelling requests on each move and sending new request on current location. If there are a lot of results on the region I am also using grouping for the pins.